# Creating and saving foreign key objects using a SlugRelatedField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've just started with Django REST framework and I'm having trouble with saving foreign keys. I have a `Merchant` model and a `Phone` model. The `Phone` has a foreign key to `Merchant`. When making a `POST` request to `Merchant`, I want to create `Phone` objects for the numbers provided in the request. But when I supply the phone numbers, it gives me the following error

> Object with phone=0123456789 does not exist.

I just want it to create the `Phone` object itself. Here are the models that I am using:

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
    merchant_id       = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name              = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active         = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'merchant'

    # Managers
    objects = models.Manager()
    active = managers.ActiveManager()

class Phone(models.Model):
    phone      = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    merchant   = models.ForeignKey('merchant.Merchant',
                                    related_name='phones',
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'phone'
```

And here is the view and serializer that I am using them with

```
class MerchantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phones = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        slug_field='phone',
        queryset=primitives.Phone.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Merchant
        fields = (
            'merchant_id',
            'name',
            'is_active',
            'phones',
        )

class MerchantViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Merchant.active.all()
    serializer_class = MerchantSerializer
```

Here's what my request body looks like:

```
{
    "merchant_id": "emp011",
    "name": "Abhinav",
    "is_active": true,
    "phones": [
        "0123456789",
        "9876543210"
    ]
}
```

Here's the response:

400 Bad Request

```
{"phones":["Object with phone=0123456789 does not exist."]}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[The `SlugRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) provided by Django REST framework, like many of the related fields, is designed to be used with objects that already exist. Since you are looking to reference objects which already exist, or object which need to be created, you aren't going to be able to use it as-is.

You will need a custom `SlugRelatedField` that creates the new object when one doesn't exist.

```
class CreatableSlugRelatedField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):
    
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**{self.slug_field: data})[0]
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            self.fail('does_not_exist', slug_name=self.slug_field, value=smart_text(data))
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            self.fail('invalid')

class MerchantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phones = CreatableSlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        slug_field='phone',
        queryset=primitives.Phone.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Merchant
        fields = (
            'merchant_id',
            'name',
            'is_active',
            'phones',
        )
```

By switching to [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), the phone number object will be created if one doesn't already exist. You may need to tweak this if there are additional fields that have to be created on the model.

Comment: Thanks! It did the trick. Now it seems so obvious that it expects a SlugRelatedField to be already created.

Comment: This is a great solution. If someone is looking to further customize it, please go through this link: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/

For instance, I found that adding required=True & allow_null=True, made it the right solution for me.

Comment: Could you add the necessary import statements to your example? Specifically `smart_text` and `ObjectDoesNotExist`.

Comment: I am also struggling to write a test that covers the two exceptions. Given you are using `get_or_create` how would one raise `ObjectDoesNotExist`?

Comment: Import ``ObjectDoesNotExist`` using ``from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist``

Answer (score 4):

Building on Kevin's answer, a little cleaner IMO due to not using `get_or_create` and `[0]`

```py
class CreatableSlugRelatedField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return self.get_queryset().get(**{self.slug_field: data})
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return self.get_queryset().create(**{self.slug_field: data})  # to create the object
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            self.fail('invalid')
```

Note the only required field in the related object should be the slug field.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a value for phone field of the object Phone. If you want create phone object without specifying value for the field phone then you have to enable null and blank fields.

```
phone = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=true,blank=true)
```

If you still experience problems, make sure the post data contains the required fields. You can use [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) for this.

Comment: Hey. I have added the request and the response. I am passing in the phone numbers (which should go into the "phone" field of Phone model as far as I know).

Comment: looks like you are trying an improper object.get in views.py. post your view also.