# ManyToMany relation custom serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Assume I have two models:

```
class IPAddress(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField()

class Rule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ips = models.ManyToMany(IPAddress)
```

I want to able to add a rule by a request as below:

```
{
"name":"Foo",
"ips":["192.168.1.40", "4.4.4.4", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

Also I want to construct ip in each request (there is no url to construct an ip directly) for new rule, so I have written a class for manager like this:

```
class RuleManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        rule = Rule(name=validate_data['name'])
        rule.save()

        rule.ips = [IPAddress.objects.get_or_create(item.lower()) for item in validated_data['ips']]
```

But in serializer I could not find a proper way to show this I have written a serializer like this:

```
class RuleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    ips = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='address', validators=[], queryset=models.IPAddress.objects.all())
```

But the problem is it validates the ip in request and if there is not such ip it returns an error, although I set the validators an empty list.

I have two questions, how can I disable this validation? And is my way for writing the serializer and model is appropriate for my scenario(I could not change the request I get and the response I must send)

Comment: Do you need the nested serializer for creating the `ips` through API or you need it just for read only where ips are already created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to return an instance of `Rule` in following format:

```
{
"name":"Foo",
"ips":["192.168.1.40", "4.4.4.4", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

You could create a `RuleSerializer` and use [`SlugRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield).

`SlugRelatedField` only works with the objects which already exist. Since you would be creating objects as well, you could modify the `to_internal_value` implementation to create the objects which doesn't exist ([referenced from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28011896/2549021)):

```
class CreatableSlugRelatedField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**{self.slug_field: data})[0]
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            self.fail('does_not_exist', slug_name=self.slug_field, value=smart_text(data))
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            self.fail('invalid')

class RuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ips = serializers.CreatableSlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        slug_field='address' # this is the ip address
        queryset=IPAddress.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
         model = Rule
         fields: ('name', 'ips')
```

---

**UPDATE:** Based on the comments in the question:

> I could not change the request I get and the response I must send

But if you could then use nested serializers though your representation would need to change slightly:

```
{
    "name": "Foo",
    "ips": [
         {"address": "192.168.1.40"}, 
         {"address": "4.4.4.4"}, 
         {"address": "8.8.8.8"}
    ]
}
```

and, then the nested serializers ([more documentation here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)):

```
class IPAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     class Meta:
         model = IPAddress
         fields: ('address',)

class RuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ips = IPAddressSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
         model = Rule
         fields: ('name', 'ips')
```

Comment: It seems like a hack, because we set `ips` read_only field but we use it for writing, also if we set it as `read_only` it will be removed from validated_data you can check this by adding `print(validated_data)` in the begging of `create` function. Also I have many nested relation with each one must construct its lower level data so I think it would be more pleasant to use `ModelManager` for constructing lower level data instead of using `create` of serializer class.

Comment: Well, this is not a hack but what is [recommended by DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers). Although you are right about using the `read_only`. It is not required here, so you could remove it in your implementation. As far as writing `create` in manager is concerned that totally depends on your requirements.

Comment: If you remove the `read_only` field then the validation problem arises as I stated in my question, because in default it checks that the `ip`  exists or not.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have to remain on the request and response form and I could not use a nested serializer.

Comment: Well, finally I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009829/creating-and-saving-foreign-key-objects-using-a-slugrelatedfield. According to this, you need to create a custom slug related field which allows creation of new objects as well.

Comment: Thanks again, it works well. If you update the answer I could check it as an accepted answer.