# Serializing one field from a ManyToManyField DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have been lot of posts, the DRF documentation (which needs LOT of love), and I couldn't find yet how to do this without a complicated mess.

I need this output:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"memcheck","subscribers":["foo", "bar"]}]
```

If I go with the DRF way (or at least how the docs point me how to do it), then I get this output:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"memcheck","subscribers":["Subscriber object", "Subscriber object"]}]
```

I tried uncommenting and going with a second option, then I get this output:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"memcheck","subscribers":[{"name": "foo"}, {"name": "bar"}]}]
```

### models.py

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Check(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
   subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(Subscriber)
```

### serializers.py

```
class SubscriberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', )


class CheckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # using source=('name') or variants like: 'subscribers__name', 'subscribers.name' 
    # doesnt work
    subscribers = serializers.ListSerializer(child=serializers.CharField())
    # subscribers = SubscriberSerializer(many=True) # --> see 2nd output

    class Meta:
        model = Check
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'subscribers')
```

In other cases of ManyToMany I would like to have the list of dict, but in this case I just want a simple list with the name attr.. why is too hard to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a [`SlugRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
class CheckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    subscribers = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='name')

    class Meta:
        model = Check
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'subscribers')
```

Comment: Ok thanks!, that worked, now I just need to receive a similar json and get the elements of the list and do get_or_create ... any ideas?

Comment: Well! If you also want to create the `subscribers` then it is going to be somewhat complex. You can follow my answer on another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686612/manytomany-relation-custom-serializer/36687891) for more details on how to achieve that.