# How to use the Django DRF serializer for ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to write a serializer for my models which has a ManyToManyField.  My problem seems to be very [similar to this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880117/serializing-one-field-from-a-manytomanyfield-drf), but at this time I'm not interested in using a SlugField and nevertheless it's not clear to me what my problem is.

models.py

```
class Objective(models.Model):
    objective_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    objective_description = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.objective_name

class Assessment(models.Model):
    objective = models.ManyToManyField(Objective)
    date_completed = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class AssessmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    objective = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Assessment
        fields = ['name', 'date_completed', 'objective']

class ObjectiveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Objective
        fields = '__all__'
```

From [the DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield), I thought that the following POST would create an Assessment object where I already have two Objective objects with id's of 3 and 4 respectively.

```
{
    "name": "Quiz 3",
    "objective": [
        3,
        4
    ]
}
```

However, this creates the Assessment object but there is no link between it and the Objectives.

```
{
    "name": "Quiz 3",
    "date_completed": "2020-03-17",
    "objective": []
}
```

Is my serializer incorrect, or am I using wrong syntax for the POST, or is there a different issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set [**`read_only=True`**--(drf doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only) in the `objective` field. If you set a field as `read_only`, DRF will not take the input data.

```
class AssessmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    objective = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, queryset=Objective.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Assessment
        fields = ['name', 'date_completed', 'objective']
```

Comment: I had tried it without the read_only=True, but that gives me this error: `Relational field must provide a 'queryset' argument, override 'get_queryset', or set read_only='True.`

Comment: @DougSmith Updated the answer.