# Django REST Framework creating foreign key object inside serializer

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Hello I'm new to REST Framework. I'm trying to make my serializer create new Town if it doesn't exist when i'm creating the new shop.

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    town = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='town', queryset=Town.objects.all())
    # town_send = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, write_only='True')

    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = ('name', 'address', 'opening_hour', 'closing_hour', 'owner', 'geo_point', 'town', 'url')
        read_only_fields = ('owner',)


    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context['request']
        owner = request.user
        town = validated_data.pop('town')
        town, exist = Town.objects.get_or_create(town=town)
        shop = Shop.objects.create(owner=owner, town=town, **validated_data)
        return shop
```

Currently it updates if I send it existing town name, but when i'm giving it new town it shows: "Object with field town=x does not exist"

EDIT:

Model:

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='name', max_length=100)
    town = models.ForeignKey('Town', verbose_name='town', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shops')
    address = models.CharField(verbose_name='address', max_length=100)
    opening_hour = models.TimeField(verbose_name='opening')
    closing_hour = models.TimeField(verbose_name='closing')
    photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name='photo', upload_to='photos', blank=True)
    geo_point = PointField(verbose_name='coordinates')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='owner', related_name='shops')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='creation date')
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='modification date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Town(models.Model):
    town = models.CharField(verbose_name='town', max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.town
```

Viewset:

```
class ShopViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows shops to be viewed, created or edited.
    """
    queryset = Shop.objects.all().order_by('-created')
    serializer_class = ShopSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

Traceback is just

```
[2018-05-09 15:12:22 +0000] [8] [DEBUG] GET /api/Shops/
[2018-05-09 15:13:13 +0000] [8] [DEBUG] POST /api/Shops/
```

Error is visible only in REST API window as json with error text written above

Comment: Can you please post the traceback ? Also viewset and model

Comment: The issue has to do with your use of `SlugRelatedField`. Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009829/creating-and-saving-foreign-key-objects-using-a-slugrelatedfield

Comment: Thank you Mekicha! It really did the trick.