# Django Rest - ManyToManyField with SlugRelatedField Data Is Not Being Created

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, slug, serialization

I have the following structure in my database:

```
{
        "name": "sum",
        "formula": "a+b",
        "date": "2020-01-17T19:02:24.143000Z",
        "tags": [
            "sum",
            "test"
        ],
        "latex": "a+b"
    }
```

**“tags”** is a field in the *Table Calculator* with ManyToManyField relationship. I used an intermediate model (*TagLink*) that specifies the foreign keys to the calculator and tag model that are involved in the ManyToMany relationship.

**Models:**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True, db_column='sTag')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tTag'

class Calculator(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True, db_column='sName')
    formula = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column='sFormula')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_column='dtModifiedDate')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='TagLink', through_fields=('calculator', 'tag'), related_name='calculator', symmetrical=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tCalculator'

class TagLink(models.Model):
    calculator = models.ForeignKey(Calculator, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='sCalculator')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='sTag')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tTagLink'
        auto_created = True
        unique_together = [['calculator', 'tag']]
```

Here is the **Serializer**:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ['name']

class CalculatorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Tag.objects.all(), slug_field='name')

    class Meta:
        model = Calculator
        fields = ['name', 'formula', 'date', 'tags']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
        calculadora = self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for tag in tags:
        obj, _ = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
        calculadora.tags.add(obj)

         calculadora.save()
         return calculadora
```

-> I'm having trouble creating a new “tag” within the **create()** method;

(1) **Condition of Success:** the tag is created successfully if it already exists in the database (TagLink table):

```
(Pdb) calc_serializer.data
{'name': 't4', 'formula': 'r', 'date': '2020-01-17T18:54:18.448332Z', 'tags': ['erika'], 'inputs': [OrderedDict([('name', 'r'), ('calculatorName', 't4'), ('isCalculator', False), ('isArray', False), ('isMatrix', False)])]}
```

(2) **Failure Condition:** if the tag does NOT exist in the database, the tag is not created and I get the following error “CalculatorNotFound”:

```
return CalculatorNotFoundException(logger, request_json['name']).response
```

Ps.: **calc_serializer.data** returns correctly. But what is happening is that calc_serializer is not validating.

Could someone help me work around this error? I am long days on end trying to find out! :/

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error! \o/

I corrected the failure condition (if the tag didn't exist in the database). I did the following:
Before saving the calculator, I first save the tags to the database. That way, I can update the tags!!!!

```
for tag_name in request_json['tags']:
            tag_object = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)
            tag_serializer = TagSerializer(data={'name': tag_name}) # -> I save first to the database

        calc_serializer = CalculatorSerializer(data=request_json)

        if calc_serializer.is_valid():
            calc_serializer.save()

            response = JsonResponse(
                calc_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

            return response
```

I am especially grateful to @DaviWesley for the help! :)

Comment: tmj! sorry for not giving the full answer I was too busy at work, I may suggest some changes to your code, when u do `tag_object =Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)` you are getting an existent tag or saving a tag, you don't need to pass data to TagSerializer because you're already have the object in the previous line, I would to change just to this `TagSerializer(tag_object[0])` imagine if you have a lot of attributes you'd have to write one by one using `data={attr1:8,attr2:737....` I would stick to the `create` method from DRF using `serializer.save()` is not ideal

Answer (score 0):

Your code is saying if I have an existing tag do a relation with Calculator, you don't need to verify if `Tag` exists you can simply use `get_or_create` [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) to get an existing `Tag` or create a new one, you are also trying to add a `string` in `Calculator` model relation, remember that in your case `validated_data.pop('tags')` is a `list` of `strings`like this `['erika']`

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
        calculadora = self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for tag in tags:
            # return the Tag object model
            obj, _ = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
            calculadora.tags.add(obj)

        calculadora.save()
        return calculadora
```

Useful learning staff:

- learn more about the `add` [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)
- learn more about the dictionary pop [method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/pop)
- learn more about [nested representation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations) from DRF

Comment: Hello Friend! First of all, thank you very much for taking the time to help me.
I implemented your solution, but unfortunately I get the same error: "CalculatorNotFoundException(logger, request_json['name']).response". I  read in this other thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009829/creating-and-saving-foreign-key-objects-using-a-slugrelatedfield) that The SlugRelatedField provided by DRF like many of the related fields is designed to be used with objects that already exist. In my case, I would like to add tags that exist/do not exist. Would this solution apply to mine? THANKS

Comment: hmm...I misunderstood your question, the get_or_create method may do the job for u when getting an existent object, but one thing that I'm not sure it is why it's raising a CalculatorNotFoundException since your SlugRelatedField is not linking to Calculator model, I'll try to find a better solution for u once I was not aware of the SlugRelatedField

Comment: and why not just use TagSerializer instead since Tag model it only has one field?

Comment: Davi, I found the error!!!!! I posted on post below :) Thank you very much for the help! \o/