# How to get foreign key reference in serializer using input value

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product(models.Model):
    channel = models.Foreignkey(Channel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

id | name
-------------
1  | Channel1
2  | Channel2
3  | Channel3
4  | Channel4
```

To create `Product` objects we simply send `id` of the `Channel` obj and serializer will be able to get the referenced object.
I have a service that exposes an endpoint and the client simply post requests to create objects. Client doesn't know about the `channel ids`, it only knows the names of the channels.

In this situation, is it possible to have a serializer where client can still send the channel names in the request but in the database they get the correct foreign key references when creating `Product` obj? Could someone point me to any examples or documentation to handle this?

**Edit**
If I were to provide `id` in my post request, the views and serializers will be as follows,

```
class ProductsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductSerializer

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

and the request body will be,

```
{
    "channel": 1
}
```

But I am looking to send the request as below but still be able to use above serializer hopefully with minor changes,

```
{
    "channel": "Channel1"
}
```

**Further Edit**
Below answer from Sasja works for me. I had to provide one additional argument `queryset`, complete serializer is shown below,

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    channel = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=False,
        read_only=False,
        slug_field='name',
        queryset=models.Channel.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

If you want to create objects of referenced model (if it doesn't exist) then we will have to extend `SlugRelatedField` as it cannot create objects by default. I found below which has an example,

[Creating and saving foreign key objects using a SlugRelatedField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009829/creating-and-saving-foreign-key-objects-using-a-slugrelatedfield)

Comment: Can you show your serializers and views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you should implement the `.create()` method on the serializer. You can then access the `validated_data` to get the Channel and create the Product with a reference to it.

```
class CreateProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        name = validated_data.get('name', False)

        # naive implementation, should still handle errors (eg. not found)
        # you need to be sure that only 1 object with that name will exist (see comment below)
        channel = Channel.objects.get(name=name)
        return Product(channel=channel)
```

If you're going to do a search on the name you should make sure that the `name` field on the `Channel` model has `unique=True`

For reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

**Edit:**
After question edit, there seems some in-built solution being the `SlugRelatedField` that is read/write by default. Also note according to the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

> When using `SlugRelatedField` as a read-write field, you will normally want to ensure that the slug field corresponds to a model field with `unique=True`.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    channel = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=False,
        read_only=False,
        slug_field='name'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes this is how I wanted to proceed but I think it is a bit fragile for the reasons you already mentioned. It only works if the name exactly matches including case. I have multiple serializers that need this so wanted to avoid duplication and wondering if there is anything builtin for this type of situations.